# how do I accomodate multiple spellings in linux if/then script?

Tags: linux, if-statement

I am new to coding and my Linux/Ubuntu assigment is requesting that I accomodate mulitple spellings for the argument in an if/then statement.  I can't find anything about this online, at least nothing with these search terms.  Can someone help?  I am using 15 workstation.

1. Write a program called isyes that returns an exit status of 0 if its argument is yes, and 1 otherwise. For purposes of this exercise, **consider y, yes, Yes, YES, and Y all to be valid yes arguments**
2. Is there a way to so thais that will not reveal all the different spellings in either the question or the response?  That is ugly.

Thank you!

Comment: You have not tagged, or mentioned, a programming language. Do you mean [tag:bash]? Also, what have you tried, before you finally came to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
read -p "Enter the answer in Y/N: " value

if [[ "$value" = [yY] ]] || [[ "$value" = [yY][eE][sS] ]];
then
     echo 0;   # Operation if true
else
     echo 1;   # Operation if false
fi
```

Comment: excellent!  thank you!  this is very clean and lovely code, much better than the instruction I am getting!  Let me know what you charge!

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this issue in many ways.
use this code on `awk` to fix your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "choose your answer [Y/N]: " input

awk -vs1="$input" 'BEGIN {
    if ( tolower(s1) == "yes" || tolower(input) == "y" ){
        print "match"
    }
    else{
        print "not match"
    }
}'
```